# Extract array's elements as object's constant properties into a temporary place

Tags: c++, linux

I am a senior PHP/Perl developer and a relative beginner in C++.

What I have is an array of objects of a class, one element of which in it's turn is an array-pointer for the subclass (if I'm using the right terms).
What I need is to process one by one the main array and extract it's elements into a separate place if they meet a certain condition (unique Name property). 
Then output extracted one with it's sub-arrays. Then output the original.

I have came up with various solutions and trying to define which is the best to use with your help.

Details.

These is the header file's part of the 2 classes I was mentioned:

```
/// class to define the modificable parameters of the machine
class CMachineParameter {
    public:
        /// Short name: "Cutoff"
        char const *Name;
        /// Longer description: "Cutoff Frequency (0-7f)"
        char const *Description;
        /// recommended >= 0. If negative, minValue is represented as 0 in the pattern
        int MinValue;
        /// recommended <= 65535. Basically so that it can be represented in the pattern
        int MaxValue;
        /// flags. (see below)
        int Flags;
        /// default value for params that have MPF_STATE flag set
        int DefValue;
};

///\name CMachineParameter flags
///\{
    /// shows a line with no text nor knob
    int const MPF_NULL = 0;
    /// shows a line with the text in a centered label
    int const MPF_LABEL = 1;
    /// shows a tweakable knob and text
    int const MPF_STATE = 2;
///\}

///\name CFxCallback::CallbackFunc codes
///\{
    int const CBID_GET_WINDOW = 0;
///\}
///\name CMachineInfo::HostEvent codes
///\{
    /// Sent by the host to ask if this plugin uses the auxiliary column. return true or false.
    int const HE_NEEDS_AUX_COLUMN = 0;
///\}

/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/// class defining the machine properties
class CMachineInfo {
    public:
        CMachineInfo(
            short APIVersion, int flags, int numParameters, CMachineParameter const * const * parameters,
            char const * name, char const * shortName, char const * author, char const * command, int numCols
        ) :
            APIVersion(APIVersion), PlugVersion(0), Flags(flags), numParameters(numParameters), Parameters(parameters),
            Name(name), ShortName(shortName), Author(author), Command(command), numCols(numCols)
        {}

        CMachineInfo(
            short APIVersion, short PlugVersion, int flags, int numParameters, CMachineParameter const * const * parameters,
            char const * name, char const * shortName, char const * author, char const * command, int numCols
        ) :
            APIVersion(APIVersion), PlugVersion(PlugVersion), Flags(flags), numParameters(numParameters), Parameters(parameters),
            Name(name), ShortName(shortName), Author(author), Command(command), numCols(numCols)
        {}

        /// API version. Use MI_VERSION
        short const APIVersion;
        /// plug version. Your machine version. Shown in Hexadecimal.
        short const PlugVersion;
        /// Machine flags. Defines the type of machine
        int const Flags;
        /// number of parameters.
        int const numParameters;
        /// a pointer to an array of pointers to parameter infos
        CMachineParameter const * const * const Parameters;
        /// "Name of the machine in listing"
        char const * const Name;
        /// "Name of the machine in machine Display"
        char const * const ShortName;
        /// "Name of author"
        char const * const Author;
        /// "Text to show as custom command (see Command method)"
        char const * const Command;
        /// number of columns to display in the parameters' window
        int numCols;
};
```

This is the code I have:

```
for(int i(0) ; i < MAX_MACHINES ; ++i) if(song.machine(i)) {
    if (song.machine(i)->GetDllName() == "") continue;
    Plugin & plug = *((Plugin*)song.machine(i));
    const psycle::plugin_interface::CMachineInfo  psycle_info = plug.GetInfo();

    // Process machine general info: psycle_info.Name, psycle_info.ShortName, psycle_info.Author etc

    if(psycle_info.numParameters > 0 && psycle_info.Parameters) {
        const int n = psycle_info.numParameters;
        for(int i(0) ; i < n; ++i) {
            const psycle::plugin_interface::CMachineParameter & psycle_param(*psycle_info.Parameters[i]);

            // Process machine's parameters: psycle_param.MinValue, psycle_param.MaxValue, psycle_param.DefValue, psycle_param.Flags etc
```

Basically, I have a list of virtual machines each with its parameters. Only ShortName differs (Machine red 1, Machine red 3, Machine grey 4). I need to output the unique machines and it's parameters by Name (Machine red, Machine grey).

In PHP I would have simply created and array like $original[psycle_info.Name] = array('author'=>psycle_info.Author, 'parameters'=>array(psycle_param.MinValue, psycle_param.MaxValue, psycle_param.DefValue, psycle_param.Flags));

In C++ I have found that I could achieve something like this with std::map and std::vector STL libraries.
This article shows a very similar problem and the solution which I came up to also from the other sources that came up to me:
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/67804-c-multidimensional-associative-arrays/

But what is the general way of doing this?
Maybe I need to create a 2 new classes of non-const elements? Or maybe a simple standard array and use standard array looping functions all the time?

Thanks very much for your attention!

**PS.** An example of data:

```
0.
Name: 'Red Machine v.098'
ShortName: 'Red Machine 1'
Author: 'Jeremy'
Parameters: 0(Name: 'OSC type', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 255, DefValue:0), 1(Name: 'CutOff', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 16555, DefValue: 1000), 2(Name: 'LFO', MinValue: 100, MaxValue: 30555, DefValue: 3000)

1.
Name: 'Red Machine v.098'
ShortName: 'Red Machine 2'
Author: 'Jeremy'
Parameters: 0(Name: 'OSC type', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 255, DefValue:0), 1(Name: 'CutOff', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 16555, DefValue: 1000), 2(Name: 'LFO', MinValue: 100, MaxValue: 30555, DefValue: 3000)

2.
Name: 'Yellow Machine v.2.4.5'
ShortName: 'Yellow Machine 1'
Author: 'Anthony'
Parameters: 0(Name: 'OSC 1 wave', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 255, DefValue: 0), 1(Name: 'OSC 2 Wave', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 255, DefValue: 0), 2(Name: 'OSC 3 Wave', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 255, DefValue: 0)

3.
Name: 'Yellow Machine v.2.4.5'
ShortName: 'Yellow Machine 2'
Author: 'Anthony'
Parameters: 0(Name: 'OSC 1 wave', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 255, DefValue: 0), 1(Name: 'OSC 2 Wave', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 255, DefValue: 0), 2(Name: 'OSC 3 Wave', MinValue: 0, MaxValue: 255, DefValue: 0)
```

Obviously, as the output in this case I would need to have 2 unique machines.

**PS2.** I will now make the further description of what I have and what needs to be done.

I have an array song.machine(i)

Algorithm:

1. As song.machine(i) info is limited, cycle through it to get another object and operate with it
2. In cycle, create Plugin (class object) plug from each song.machine(i) so finally can get 
   object CMachineInfo psycle_info via psycle_info = plug.GetInfo();
   which has all the information we need to output
3. Compare Name in psycle_info.Name. If it has been shown already, skip to the next.
   Otherwise, output the data.

This is the header file I am including which contains the 2 classes I've shown originally:
http://sourceforge.net/p/psycle/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/psycle-plugins/src/psycle/plugin_interface.hpp

To sum up again: as I can access objects iteratively only, plus I need to perform some operations on the data (like replace all spaces to '+' in Name), I thought of creating a temporary array/class. But probably, it would be enough to create a simple array char nameShown[100] where I can store all the names that are shown already and with each song.machine(i) iteration, cycle through whole nameShown and if it contains current Name, continue to the next.
I just didn't want to cycle through "nameShown" every time and in PHP we could use associative arrays for this: so I can only check if ($nameShown[$Name]) exists or no.
It also appeared to me a headache that like you said, I cannot copy properties and parameters because they are constants!!
Seemed like a very simple task, but so hard for a beginner like me.
Hope I've covered all the confusing points!

**PS4.** I have just also updated the topic's name so it would contain "constant" mentioning.

**PS5.** Here is the code that basically should do what I need:

```
std::string nameShown[100];
bool should_skip = false;
for (int k(0); k < i; k++) {
    if (nameShown[k] == psycle_info.Name) {
        should_skip = true;
    }
}
if(should_skip)  continue;
    nameShown[i] = psycle_info.Name;
std::ostringstream l; l << "Plugin: " << psycle_info.Name; loggers::warning()(l.str());
```

So the full piece would look like:

```
std::string nameShown[100];
for(int i(0) ; i < MAX_MACHINES ; ++i) if(song.machine(i)) {
    if (song.machine(i)->GetDllName() == "") continue;
    Plugin & plug = *((Plugin*)song.machine(i));
    const psycle::plugin_interface::CMachineInfo  psycle_info = plug.GetInfo();

    // Process machine general info: psycle_info.Name, psycle_info.ShortName, psycle_info.Author etc
    bool should_skip = false;
    for (int k(0); k < i; k++) {
        if (nameShown[k] == psycle_info.Name) {
            should_skip = true;
        }
    }
    if(should_skip)  continue;
    nameShown[i] = psycle_info.Name;
    std::ostringstream l; l << "Plugin: " << psycle_info.Name; loggers::warning()(l.str());

    if(psycle_info.numParameters > 0 && psycle_info.Parameters) {
        const int n = psycle_info.numParameters;
        for(int i(0) ; i < n; ++i) {
            const psycle::plugin_interface::CMachineParameter & psycle_param(*psycle_info.Parameters[i]);

            // Process machine's parameters: psycle_param.MinValue, psycle_param.MaxValue, psycle_param.DefValue, psycle_param.Flags etc
```

The output before the cycle inserted:

```
log:  446322us: W: main: Plugin: Sublime 1.1
log:  446413us: W: main: Plugin: Pooplog FM UltraLight0.68b
log:  446497us: W: main: Plugin: Phantom 1.2
log:  446581us: W: main: Plugin: Pooplog FM UltraLight0.68b
log:  446649us: W: main: Plugin: FeedMe 1.2
log:  446729us: W: main: Plugin: Drum Synth v.2.5
log:  446793us: W: main: Plugin: Sublime 1.1
log:  446876us: W: main: Plugin: Arguru Compressor
log:  446945us: W: main: Plugin: Pooplog Filter 0.06b
log:  447016us: W: main: Plugin: Slicit
log:  447095us: W: main: Plugin: EQ-3
log:  447163us: W: main: Plugin: Arguru Compressor
log:  447231us: W: main: Plugin: Pooplog Filter 0.06b
log:  447294us: W: main: Plugin: Koruz
log:  447361us: W: main: Plugin: Pooplog Filter 0.06b
log:  447425us: W: main: Plugin: EQ-3
log:  447496us: W: main: Plugin: Arguru Compressor
log:  447558us: W: main: Plugin: EQ-3
```

After:

```
log:  414242us: W: main: Plugin: Sublime 1.1
log:  414331us: W: main: Plugin: Pooplog FM UltraLight0.68b
log:  414415us: W: main: Plugin: Phantom 1.2
log:  414499us: W: main: Plugin: FeedMe 1.2
log:  414560us: W: main: Plugin: Drum Synth v.2.5
log:  414622us: W: main: Plugin: Arguru Compressor
log:  414694us: W: main: Plugin: Pooplog Filter 0.06b
log:  414761us: W: main: Plugin: Slicit
log:  414830us: W: main: Plugin: EQ-3
log:  414897us: W: main: Plugin: Koruz
```

Note, in the newly added cycle, I have tried to use for (int k(0); k < sizeof(nameShown); k++) which sounded to me more obvious as for a PHP programmer, but even on a first song.machine(i) iteration, it loops itself for pretty many times and then gives a segfault, so I've changed this to "k < i".

This is basically what I was needed. And was just curious if it's the right way of doing, because looping every time through non existent elements of the filter array sounds primitive and ineffective to me.

Another thing is that after the output of the unique machines, which I have just accomplished, I would need to output the whole list. So what, I would have to create the whole song.machine(i) cycle again, so to avoid code repetition, I was thought of extraction of the values I need into a simpler data handles. In PHP I would have used associative arrays for this.

Again, to sum up, first I need to output the unique machines list and then all of them with different details set for each list.

Probably, as it seems to complex to explain (but it's a very simple task actually, XML generation) I will stick to what works and seeking for which code is best is may be too luxurious in this case.

Comment: Could you explain your problem more clearly?  I don't quite get it.

Comment: Sure. As you can see in the code, I have an array of objects song.machine(i) from element of each, I can get another object - psycle_info. In it's turn it has an array of objects psycle_info.Parameters. I need to output all psycle_info elements but only having unique psycle_info.Name. See corrected and updated with data example post. Hope I was clear enough!

Answer (score 0):

Lets start with what is clear, you have a array song.machine(i)

Algorithm:

1. Compare Names in song.machine(i)
2. If Match, Dynamic Cast  song.machine(i) to Plugin (class object) plug
3. Use this to make object CMachineInfo psycle_info via psycle_info = plug.GetInfo();
4. Process this data / Output / **Extract it ?**.

Lets start with what you have written in class definition:

- **char***

  A char*, declared allocates memory on heap/Stack. This in turn has to be deleted as objects are destroyed in application. Your code is creating a lot of objects then you copy them, pass them around to another objects. The memory location for pointer is not allocated (e.g. new [] operator / malloc) which would eventually be overwritten by any type / Object data. You may not get segmentation fault sometimes, but your data is surely not safe in such case.

  In such a case you should use **string**, in-built char* or char arrays. They allocate and destroy on their own. So no memory faults and also the functions like string.compare() can be easy to use. refer [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/)
- [**Copy / Assignment Operator**](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/y8hv0pDG/)

  Copy and Assignment operator (e.g. CMachineInfo obj1 = CMachineInfo Obj2) work on object of a class and as name suggest they are meant to pass on data among objects. C++ defines by default, operators for you. But the behavior is tricky when you are dealing with pointers. You can override this by defining what you want (See Below).
- **Const members**

  In c++ class, members can be const (integers with no work around) with a rule, **Objects with const members cannot be used in COPY AND ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR**. It is simple to understand. You have a object say obj1, now you want to copy all its content to another object obj2 (of same class). When Obj2 is created, it members get defined as constant and now you are trying to overwrite the values. The compiler wont allow this. The work around such a problem is that you declare such members as **private**. Private members aren't allowed access directly (e.g. pyscle_info.Name). You have to write a public function which in turn can deliver this access to them (e.g. pyscle_info.GET_NAME_OF_MACHINE();)

Let look at the modified code CMachineParameter:

```
class CMachineParameter{

public:

    CMachineParameter(string Name, string Description, int MinValue, 
                        int MaxValue, int Flags, int DefValue
    ): Name(Name), Description(Description), MinValue(MinValue), MaxValue(MaxValue), Flags(Flags), DefValue(DefValue)
    {}

    /*DeFault Constructor*/
    CMachineParameter(): Name("TEST"), Description("Temp Object")
    {}

    //  Copy Constructor
    CMachineParameter(const CMachineParameter &TO_BE_COPIED)
    : Name(TO_BE_COPIED.Name), Description(TO_BE_COPIED.Description), MinValue(TO_BE_COPIED.MinValue),
      MaxValue(TO_BE_COPIED.MaxValue) ,Flags(TO_BE_COPIED.Flags), DefValue(TO_BE_COPIED.DefValue)
    {}

    //  Assignment Operator
    CMachineParameter & operator=(const CMachineParameter & TO_BE_Assigned)
    {
        if(this != &TO_BE_Assigned)
        {
            Name        = TO_BE_Assigned.Name;
            Description = TO_BE_Assigned.Description;
            MinValue    = TO_BE_Assigned.MinValue;
            MaxValue    = TO_BE_Assigned.MaxValue;
            Flags       = TO_BE_Assigned.Flags;
            DefValue    = TO_BE_Assigned.DefValue;
        }

        return *this;
    }

    void show(void) const;

    /*To access the Private members*/
    std::string GET_NAME(void) const;

    /// recommended >= 0. If negative, minValue is represented as 0 in the pattern
    int MinValue;
    /// recommended <= 65535. Basically so that it can be represented in the pattern
    int MaxValue;
    /// flags. (see below)
    int Flags;
    /// default value for params that have MPF_STATE flag set
    int DefValue;

private:
    /*
     * Making them as Private as Assignment and copy operator Cannot be used with Const members.
    */
    /// Short name: "Cutoff"
    string Name;
    /// Longer description: "Cutoff Frequency (0-7f)"
    string Description;
};

void CMachineParameter::show() const
{
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------\n";
    cout << "My Machine " << Name << endl
         << "\t" << Description << endl
         << "\tMinValue:    " << MinValue << endl
         << "\tMaxValue:    " << MaxValue << endl
         << "\tFlags:       " << Flags << endl
         << "\tDefValue:    " << DefValue << endl;
    cout << "------------------------------------------------------\n";
}

std::string CMachineParameter::GET_NAME(void) const
{
    return Name;
}
```

**For CMachineInfo you need to implement the Assignment / Copy Operator.** I implemented a vector of CMachineParameter const *.

```
class CMachineInfo {
    public:
        CMachineInfo(
            short APIVersion, int flags, int numParameters,
            string name, string shortName, string author, string command, int numCols
        ) :
            APIVersion(APIVersion), PlugVersion(0), Flags(flags), numParameters(numParameters),
            Name(name), ShortName(shortName), Author(author), Command(command), numCols(numCols)
        {}

        CMachineInfo(
            short APIVersion, short PlugVersion, int flags, int numParameters,
            string name, string shortName, string author, string command, int numCols
        ) :
            APIVersion(APIVersion), PlugVersion(PlugVersion), Flags(flags), numParameters(numParameters),
            Name(name), ShortName(shortName), Author(author), Command(command), numCols(numCols)
        {}

        //  Copy Constructor
        CMachineInfo (const CMachineInfo &TO_BE_COPIED)
        : APIVersion(TO_BE_COPIED.APIVersion), PlugVersion(TO_BE_COPIED.PlugVersion),
        Flags(TO_BE_COPIED.Flags), numParameters(TO_BE_COPIED.numParameters), Name(TO_BE_COPIED.Name),
        ShortName(TO_BE_COPIED.ShortName), Author(TO_BE_COPIED.Author), Command(TO_BE_COPIED.Command),
        numCols(TO_BE_COPIED.numCols), Parameter(TO_BE_COPIED.Parameter)
        {}

        //  Assignment Operator
        CMachineInfo & operator=(const CMachineInfo &TO_BE_Assigned)
        {
            if(this != &TO_BE_Assigned)
            {
                APIVersion      = TO_BE_Assigned.APIVersion; 
                PlugVersion     = TO_BE_Assigned.PlugVersion;
                Flags           = TO_BE_Assigned.Flags;
                numParameters   = TO_BE_Assigned.numParameters; 
                Name            = TO_BE_Assigned.Name;
                ShortName       = TO_BE_Assigned.ShortName; 
                Author          = TO_BE_Assigned.Author; 
                Command         = TO_BE_Assigned.Command;
                numCols         = TO_BE_Assigned.numCols;
                Parameter       = TO_BE_Assigned.Parameter;
            }
            return *this;
        }

        void SHOW(void) const;

        /// a pointer to an array of pointers to parameter infos
        /// CMachineParameter const * const * const Parameters;
        vector<CMachineParameter const *> Parameter;

        /// "Name of the machine in listing"
        std::string Name;

        /// "Name of the machine in machine Display"
        std::string ShortName;

        /// "Name of author"
        std::string Author;

        /// "Text to show as custom command (see Command method)"
        std::string Command;

        /// number of columns to display in the parameters' window
        int numCols;

private:
        /// API version. Use MI_VERSION
        short APIVersion;

        /// plug version. Your machine version. Shown in Hexadecimal.
        short PlugVersion;

        /// Machine flags. Defines the type of machine
        int Flags;

        /// number of parameters.
        int numParameters;
};

void CMachineInfo::SHOW() const
{
    cout << "My Machine IS: " << endl
         << "\tAPIVersion:    " << APIVersion << endl
         << "\tPlugVersion:   " << PlugVersion << endl
         << "\tFlags:         " << Flags << endl
         << "\tnumParameters: " << numParameters << endl
         << "\tName:          " << Name << endl
         << "\tShortName:     " << ShortName << endl
         << "\tAuthor:        " << Author << endl
         << "\tCommand:       " << Command << endl
         << "\tnumCols:       " << numCols << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attempt, but you misunderstood me.. I cannot modify the classes! They are from the working program! I can only include the header files! That's exactly why I mentioned "extraction". Especially because of the constants I started to seek for the help. I cannot do anything with the objects, but I need to output only unique ones. I will make now a PS2 in the original post as this box is very limited.

Comment: What about the code your wrote (in your question song.machines(i)..)?
Does it compile ? if not what errors ?

Comment: Please, disregard the previous reply. Every code I've shown compiles well. See PS5 for the final clarification. Thanks for your efforts again!